# Sub Scope Not Updated In Group by ng-repeat Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I Have Ng-repeat CheckBoxes List In My AngularJs Application

```
"(key, value) in MyScopeModel| groupBy: 'Filed'"
```

Every Check Box List Has One Check Box To Select This Group All Or UnSelect
The Problem Is When I Update `$scope.MyScopeModel` Not Update  value So The Check Boxes Not Work As Expected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/412cK.jpg)

**Note:** this MY Customer Group By Filter

```
App.filter('groupBy', function () {
    return _.memoize(function (items, field) {
        return _.groupBy(items, field);
    }
    );
});
```

This My Code :

```
<div class="panel-group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in MyScopeModel| groupBy: 'Filed'">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{ 'm-' + ($index + 1)  }}">{{($index + 1) + ' - ' + key }}</a>
                    </h4>

                    <input type="checkbox" ng-init="isMAllSelected=checkboxes[$index + 1]" ng-model="isMAllSelected"
                           ng-click="toggleMAll($index + 1)"/> SellectAll

                </div>
                <div ng-attr-id="{{ 'm-' + ($index + 1)  }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body col-sm-12 table-responsive achievements">

                        <ul ng-repeat="k in value">

                            <li>

                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="k.Status"/>
                                </label>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


$scope.MyScopeModel=date;// This Comming From Database and It Work as Expected The Problem Is When Update $scope.MyScopeModel value in ng-repeat not updated


    $scope.toggleMAll = function (index) {
        var toggleMStatus = $scope.checkboxes[index];
        angular.forEach($scope.MyScopeModel, function (itm) {
            if (itm.Mid === index) {
                itm.Status = toggleMStatus;

            }

        });


    }
```

Comment: Can you show `MyScopeModel` and some more of the relevant HTML?

Comment: $scope.MyScopeModel=date;// This Comming From Database and It Work as Expected The Problem Is When Update $scope.MyScopeModel value in ng-repeat not updated
    $scope.toggleMAll = function (index) {
        var toggleMStatus = $scope.checkboxes[index];
        angular.forEach($scope.MyScopeModel, function (itm) {
            if (itm.Mid === index) {
                itm.Status = toggleMStatus;
            }
        });
    }

Comment: Did this work for you?